# External API credential storage and retrieval

Tags: api, integration, customsetting

I'm integrating with a third party API and need to store the (application-wide) credentials in Salesforce. The API requires a token for authentication, which is generated by using a username and password through the API.

**What I have done so far:**

I currently have the username, password, and token saved in a Custom Setting. ***I have already written the code*** that successfully makes a call to the third party API, retrieves a new token and stores it on the Custom Setting, but the token may expire or the username or password may change at some point in the future. I am looking for a flexible place to store this data so that it can be updated if needed, and from what I've encountered so far, Custom Settings might not be the best place.

**Here is my question:**

- Can I execute Apex code when a certain Custom Setting is saved, or embed a button on the Custom Setting page that executes the code

**-or-**

- Shoud I move the credentials to somewhere secure that will allow manipulation on save or with a button? If so, where?

Again, **NOT ASKING FOR ANY CODE**, just advice :) any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated!

**=====EDIT=====**

This question has gotten multiple downvotes with no explanation. If this is not a good question or there is detail missing, please leave a comment and let me know whats wrong with it. Simply downvoting and moving on does not increase the quality of this or any future questions. If my question sucks i can accept that, but let's at least try to improve the community by letting me know what's wrong with it and how to improve it!

Comment: The typical process with expiring tokens is to make the normal callout, catch if you get a  Unauthorized response, then call to get a new token and repeat the original call. Then save new token. In general questions asking for code to be given to you, may not be your intent but you are giving a requirement and not showing any effort to try it yourself and ask when you get stuck, get down votes / closed. Also, questions with broad focus where there could be many possible ways to do things, require a lot of detail to narrow the focus

Comment: @Eric, thanks for the response and I completely understand where you are coming from. In this case, I am not asking for code (I've already got the code written), I'm looking for advice on where to store the data. As stated in my question, I am currently storing the data in a Custom Setting, but I can't attach a trigger to that to fire my code. My question is where CAN I store this data to best complete the task. I've also edited my question for clarification. thanks!

Comment: Why would you need a trigger. That is the crux of the question and my comment. I took your question as a trigger to refresh the token. That is not the accepted / appropriate way to do it.